# Use struct object inside a class

Tags: c++, class

I have the following code in C++

A.hpp

```
struct A
{
public:
    A(int _a)
    :
    a(_a){}

    int a;
};
```

B.hpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

class B
{
public:
    B(A a); // error variable "A" is not a type name
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have included the header for A in B.hpp

Comment: The code you show shouldn't produce that error. The problem likely lies in the code you haven't shown. Say, do you by any chance include `B.hpp` in `A.hpp`?

Comment: How are you building your code? As Igor said your code looks fine. The problem is most likely how you are building your code.

Comment: Not enough detail here to ascertain the problem, you'll also need the `cpp` files and the command line used to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I was doing something wrong in the code that I have not shown.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You probably should delete the question. It won't help any future reader solve a problem.